# Setting up midiIO library on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, midi

I've downloaded the midiIO library and in the readme it says:

> 1. edit the file Makefile.library and set the OSTYPE and OSSUBTYPE to match your hardware/os setup.
> 2. type "make library" to compile the library.  It will be created as lib/libmidiio.a in unix.
> 3. edit the file Makefile.examples and set the OSTYPE and OSSUBTYPE to match your hardware/os setup.
>      Also, if you are using ALSA, then uncomment out the POSTFLAG to use the alsa library (-lasound).
> 4. type "make examples" to compile the example programs in the examples directory.  The example programs will be place in the bin directory.

1 + 3 are fine but 2 + 4 are over my head. I've worked in a unix environment before and have used gcc with flags but I need to get this done in Windows. I typically use Visual Studio but don't know how to achieve this with that.. I've downloaded Dev-C++ if that's any use but I don't know what to do with the makefiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the makefiles and set up a fresh project in Visual C++. Make your target a static library (which will be a .lib file in Win32, not a .a file as in unix as you probably know). It is unlikely that the project will build out of the box, so you might have to deal with some compilation errors relating to unix-specific symbols. I took a quick look at the source code, and it looks fairly well-written, so I don't think you should have many problems building it directly in Windows.

Alternately, you could build the source using the real `make` tool in cygwin, but this means that you would need to distribute the cygwin library with your final product. This may or may not be more trouble than it's worth, especially if you are already using VC++ for the rest of your project's code.